# удаление програмно созданной кнопки

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

в фрагменте из кода создается кнопка.

```
binCl = FragmentSubjectsListBinding.inflate(inflater)

private var subjectsButtons = emptyArray<Button>()

val newButton = Button(context)
subjectsButtons += newButton
binCl.linearLayout.addView(newButton)
```

в случае некоторых операций, ее надо полностью удалить. как это сделать?

Comment: Сохраните ссылку на кнопку и удаляйте. Ну или программно еë ищите и удаляйте

Comment: я могу ее найти, но не знаю как удалить

Comment: Вроде бы есть метод а-ля `addView`. Что-то типа `removeView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

важно понять что все элементы представляют собой `view`. Для удаление определенного `view` используется функция `removeView` у `ViewGroup`. Конкретно на вашем примере это

```
binCl.linearLayout?.removeView(newButton)
```

или

```
(newButton.getParent() as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(newButton)
```

---

не забываем что `getParent()` может быть `null` или же `binCl.linearLayout` может не содержать `newButton`

Answer (score 0):

```
binCl.linearLayout.removeView(newButton)
```